# hardware acceleration and context switching overhead

Tags: cryptography, device-driver, hardware-acceleration

If the host software willing to take advantage of the H/W is based in user-space, how is it possible to mitigate overhead of context switching, data copying etc.? For example, OpenSSL is in the user space, it should be able to speak to a driver via I/O control or similar, send/receive data buffers, all these would result in extensive use of syscalls. What would be the benefit of hardware then?

Comment: Don't confuse the overhead of making a kernel call with the overhead of making thousands of complex mathematical operations. Besides, not all hardware-related operations require kernel drivers or context switches. Using SIMD CPU operations for example, doesn't involve drivers at all. Other operations work on buffers or streams of data so the overhead of a switch is minimal compared to the overall work. Anyway, this is *far* too broad a subject

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, thanks for quick feedback! I do understand the subject is complex and broad, I would be happy to read some materials on this, if you could recommend any books/papers? I also know that some H/W accelerators use microcode loaded on the cores and the microcde does the most 'heavy lifting' activities.

Comment: OpenSSL uses engines, which are basically pieces of C code, and the C code can more or less do anything